# What is the correct way to run a Windows 10 *Education* virtual machine on Linux?

Tags: windows, elementary-os, gnome-boxes

I installed Windows 10 Education (Win10E) in Gnome Boxes on elementary OS 6 (Odin).
As far as I can tell, it installs fine, and I can use Win10E with my university account.
However, if I restart my computer or Gnome Boxes, the Win10E login screen will not accept my password, and I cannot log back into Win10E.
Win10E acts as though my password is wrong, but it is not.

Gnome Boxes also offers the option to install Win10E with a local account.
I can add a local account, which allows me to log back into Win10E.
However, there is a warning in the lower-right corner of the screen that I am in “test mode”.
It seems that test mode means that I have an unsigned driver.
I found [this guidance](https://windowsloop.com/disable-test-mode-windows-10/) on how to remove the test-mode warning.
However, I prefer to not blindly silence warnings if I can fix the underlying situation.

What is the correct way to run a Windows 10 *Education* virtual machine on Linux?
I am open to other virtual machines, and all I really need is full access to Office 365 (i.e., not the web version).

Comment: Does the windows-problem also exist, when using different/standard HV-Infrastructure/Viewers like Debian/Virt-manager?

Comment: @AlexStragies — Thanks! `virt-manager` solves the problem. I installed Windows 10 Education in `virt-manager`, and everything seems to work great after a few reboots of the VM. I am happy to mark your comment as correct if you make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had never encountered issues like you mentioned myself, when installing the virt-manager on standard Debian to run Win10E in VMs.

So I suggested in a comment to simply/standardize the tech-stack used. A subsequent comment by OP indicated, that indeed -in this case- using `virt-manager` instead of `gnome-boxes` solved the issue here, so repost as solution

Comment: I realized today that I set a PIN for the virt-manager install and had been using the PIN to successfully login. Today, I tried the password, and was unable to login. My password contains @. Is it possible that both virt-manager and boxes pass the incorrect @ symbol? For example, a unicode @ instead of an ASCII @? I do not understand text encoding.